# NLog layout variable evaluates blank

Tags: layout, mono, nlog

I am on NLog 4.3.5.

I have a long, complicated layout string that I want to save in a `<variable />` for use in four `layout` attributes. Unfortunately, if I refer to the variable using

```
layout="${layout_full}"
```

then NLog complains that it cannot find that layout formatter (even though it isn't a layout formatter, it's a variable); and if I refer to the variable using

```
layout="${var:layout_full}"
```

then the layout evaluates to a blank string.

In other words, this:

```
    <variable name="layout-full" value="
${longdate} [${level}] ${logger} ${all-event-properties}${newline}
${message}
${when:when='${exception}'!='':inner=
${newline}${exception}
${newline}${stacktrace}}
" />
    <target name="stdout" xsi:type="Console" error="false" layout="a${var:layout-full}b" />
```

shows all log entries as "ab".

I have also tried putting all four targets into a `SplitGroup` and applying a layout to the group, but that's apparently unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the case here, but the `<variable>` should be outside the `<target>` **and** `<targets>`

Comment: Yep. I wonder (a) how you knew that and (b) why NLog silently fails rather than either working or issuing an error.

Comment: There should be a xsd warning in the internal log AFAIK.  And it's a common mistake ;)